# knockoutjs mvc button action change per viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

I am currently using knockoutjs with one of my MVC applications.
The Layout template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid head-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/logo.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a class="block" href="#" style="display: none" data-bind="visible: showBack, click: goBack">
                    <div class="block-text">
                        <h4>Back</h4>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a class="block" href="#" style="display: none" data-bind="visible: showHome, click: navigateToHome">
                    <div class="block-text">
                        <h4>Home</h4>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

and my **Index** partial looks like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Login")
@Html.Partial("_Home")
@Html.Partial("_CutLengths")
@Html.Partial("_MoveStock")

@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
}
```

My problem is that depending on which **page** I am on, I would like to use the back button to go to another **page**. For example, if I am on **cutLengths** I would want the back button to take me **home**.

My **app.viewmodel.js** has a method which looks like this:

```
// Other operations
self.addViewModel = function (options) {
    var viewItem = {},
        navigator;

    // Add view to AppViewModel.Views enum (for example, app.Views.Home).
    self.Views[options.name] = viewItem;

    // Add binding member to AppViewModel (for example, app.home);
    self[options.bindingMemberName] = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.view() !== viewItem) {
            return null;
        }

        return new options.factory(self, dataModel);
    });

    if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
        navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
    } else {
        navigator = function () {
            self.view(viewItem);
        };
    }

    // Add navigation member to AppViewModel (for example, app.NavigateToHome());
    self["navigateTo" + options.name] = navigator;
};
```

What I would like to do is pass a string from the **ViewModel** I am currently viewing which when the back button is pressed will know to direct me to the right **ViewModel**.

Is it possible to do this?

I hope I have explained it well, if I haven't please ask and I will try harder :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this now. First I changed my HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <a class="block btn-back" href="#" data-bind="visible: showBack, click: goBack"></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <a class="block btn-home" href="#/home" data-bind="visible: showHome"></a>
</div>
```

Then I edited my **app.viewmodel.js** file and added these

```
// Data
self.back = ko.observable(null);


// UI state
self.showBack = ko.observable(true);
self.showHome = ko.observable(true);
self.goBack = function () {
    if (self.back()) {
        window.location.href = self.back();
    } else {
        window.history.back();
    }

    self.back(null); // Reset
};
self.setBackUrl = function (url) {
    self.back(url);
}
```

Then on my **addViewModel** navigate function, I added this:

```
if (typeof (options.navigatorFactory) !== "undefined") {
    navigator = options.navigatorFactory(self, dataModel);
} else {
    navigator = function () { // This is our navigator function which sets the current view
        self.showBack(true);
        self.showHome(true);
        self.error(null); // Reset errors

        self.view(viewItem);
    };
}
```

And then in my other view models, I just make a call to **setBackUrl** like this:

```
app.setBackUrl("#/cut-lengths");
```

And if I want to hide my buttons, that is easy too. I just create a **navigatorFactory** on the viewModel like this:

```
app.addViewModel({
    name: "Home",
    bindingMemberName: "home",
    factory: HomeViewModel,
    navigatorFactory: function (app) {
        return function () {
            app.showBack(false);
            app.showHome(false);
            app.error(null);

            app.view(app.Views.Home);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either ViewData or ViewBag for passing data from the controller to view. So one option is to just add a few dynamic properties to ViewBag for current view model and prior view model.

**ViewData** is a dictionary of objects that are stored and retrieved using strings as keys.

**ViewBag** uses the  dynamic feature that was introduced into C# 4.It allows an object to have properties dynamically added to it. I would use this for passing your view model state around.

Neither provide compile time checking, which is the beauty of them, you can add anything you want. With that said it’s always good practice to use strongly typed view models over ViewBag and ViewData.

If you'd rather put something in your view model instead of adding properties to ViewBag, than just add another property in each view model called PreviousViewModel and populate it any time you use the model.

Examples using ViewBag or ViewData

```
ViewData["LastViewModel"] = "CutLengths";
ViewBag.LastViewModel = "CutLengths";
```

Access your ViewBag in the Views is no problem, they have global scope. ViewBag is like a global variable that you can attach anything to-- so I'd use them judiciously-- maybe some type of a singleton application manager would be a better design.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I think you are a bit confused too :) This is not MVC I am talking about, this is knockout js :(

Comment: Oh, shoot. My bad. It was late when I made this answer. lol sorry.